# Storing bookmarks outside of chrome root folders?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, bookmarks

I'm currently making a chrome extension for managing bookmarks, but whenever I try to do an action on them, it gives me the error "Can't modify the root bookmark folders.", Is there any way to bypass this, or possibly, is there any way the user can store bookmarks outside of the root folder?

(The action where it stucks:

```js
chrome.bookmarks.getTree(function(bookmarks) {
            console.log(bookmarks)
            for (let i = 0; i < bookmarks.length; i++) {
                console.log(bookmarks[i].children)
                for (let j = 0; j < bookmarks[i].children.length; j++) {
                    let arr = bookmarks[i].children
                    chrome.bookmarks.remove(arr[j].id)
                }
            }
        })
```

)

Thanks for reading!